# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'area'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'area' .
I wanna parse excel and put it to the model(City&Prefecture&Area&User) .
I wrote

```
fourrows_transpose = list(map(list, zip(*fourrows)))
val3 = sheet3.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=9)
user3 = Companyransaction.objects.filter(corporation_id=val3)
print(user3)
if user3:
   area = Area.objects.filter(name="America")
   pref = Prefecture.objects.create(name="prefecture", area=user3.area)
   city = City.objects.create(name="city", prefecture=pref)
   price_u1000 = Price.upper1000.objects.get(city=city)
   price_500_1000 = Price.from500to1000.objects.get(city=city)
   price_u500 = Price.under500.objects.get(city=city)

   pref.name = "NY"
   pref.save()

   for i in range(len(fourrows_transpose)):
       city.name = fourrows_transpose[i][1]
       city.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][1])

       price_u1000.name = fourrows_transpose[i][2]
       price_u1000.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][2])

       price_500_1000.name = fourrows_transpose[i][3]
       price_500_1000.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][3])

       price_u500.name = fourrows_transpose[i][4]
       price_u500.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][4])
```

models.py is

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='area', null=True)
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area',null=True, blank=True)

class Prefecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='prefecture')
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area', null=True, blank=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='city')
    prefecture = models.ForeignKey('Prefecture', null=True, blank=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='price')
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', null=True, blank=True)
```

I wanna put these data

```
[['America', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'u1000', '500～1000', 'd500'], ['NY', 'City A', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City B', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City C', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City D', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City E', '×', '×', '×']]
```

to models which is like 'America' to Prefecture's area and City A to City's name and ×　to Price's name . How can I fix this?What should I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this error since you are attempting to access `.area` on a queryset not on a single `Companyransaction` instance. When you do a `.filter` a queryset is returned. If you are sure only a single object will be returned i would suggest you change:

```
user3 = Companyransaction.objects.filter(corporation_id=val3)
```

to this:

```
user3 = Companyransaction.objects.get(corporation_id=val3)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `user3` is a QuerySet, not a model instance.

`filter` always returns a QuerySet, even if there is only a single match. If you want an instance, you should use `.get`:

```
user3 = Companyransaction.objects.get(corporation_id=val3)
```